# iOS - Error on publishing iOS application from Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin, itunes

I want to publish our **iOS** application to **iTunes** using **Xcode** but I get the following errors.

- Your application contains **non-public API** usage. Please review the errors, correct them, and resubmit your application.
- The app references non-public symbols in Payload/XXXXXX.app/XXXXXX: **NSZombieEnabled** if you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.cpm. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information page at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical.

We use **Xamarin studio** to code the application, before this we published our application many times without any error, but we cant update it to new version, and in this new version we only changed some **fonts** and **colors** and I think this errors are not correct.

I know that there is some same problems for others and I read all this questions and asnwers but I cant fix the issue.

I enabled **NSZombie** in the settings but nothing changed.

Please let me know if you need more informations to help me solve this issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to publish a debug build.

Uncheck "Enable debugging" in the project's iOS Build options.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off zombies, and search for underscores in your code (its going to be a pain) to find uses of private API. If it doesn't work, contact apple.

Comment: We only used Google Places API Key , and I changed it to new one , but still I got the errors